# Create new shapely polygon by finding the overlapping area

Tags: python, polygon, openstreetmap, area, shapely

I have two polygons the red one and yellow one obtained from osm map. I want to extract the overlapping area as a polygon.

`pol.intersects(pol2)`

shapely gives the coordinates of only the red line. but i want to get the whole overlapped area as polygon.

[image]

Comment: There is no `intersect` method in Shapely, but only `intersects` and `intersection`. Which one did you use? From the looks of it, `intersection` should return you a `Polygon` object, so I'm not sure how you got that thin red line. Please, provide a code example so that we could reproduce the issue.

Comment: My bad i didn't evaluate it properly, actually one of the Polygon returned from a function wasn't a polygon but a line and instead of giving whole intersection area it gave me the points of line which are inside the polygon2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of shapely are you using? To intersect to polygons in `1.6.4.post2` use the following code example:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
a = Point(1, 1).buffer(1.5)
b = Point(2, 1).buffer(1.5)
```

This creates two circle polygons that look like

[image]

```
a.intersection(b)
```

The result is a polygon and will look like

[image]